# IEqualityComparer on Dictionary inside Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, dictionary

I want to create a `Dictionary<DateTime, Dictionary<APerson, AVisit>>` struct and I want to supply an `IEqualityComparer` on the **second** dictionary that holds an `APerson` as key

If I only had the inner dictionary it would be

```
var f = new Dictionary<APerson, AVisit>(new PersonEqualityComparer());
```

But I cannot find a constructor to supply it in the declaration. Do I have to pass it in every child declaration of `Dictionary<APerson, AVisit>` or is possible to instruct the mother struct to have a specified `IEqualityComparer` all the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I have to pass it in every child declaration of Dictionary

Yes (if by this you mean every instance of `Dictionary<APerson, AVisit>`).

> or is possible to instruct the mother struct to have a specified IEqualityComparer all the time?

No.

But, you can reorganize. Instead of

```
Dictionary<DateTime, Dictionary<APerson, AVisit>>
```

why not

```
Dictionary<Tuple<DateTime, APerson>, AVisit>
```

Then you can supply exactly one instance of something that implements

```
IEqualityComparer<Tuple<DateTime, APerson>>
```

You might even replace `Tuple<DateTime, APerson>` with a custom type.

Comment: Im on `.Net3.5` there is no `Tuple` there

Comment: @odyodyodys: Your point that you can't use the `Tuple` that came with .NET in 4.0 is irrelevant. You can write your own (it's not hard) or use a custom type like I mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

> Do I have to pass it in every child declaration of Dictionary

Yes because the value of the outer dictionary is a dictionary. So everytime you insert a value in this outer dictionary you are actually some dictionary that you instantiated somewhere else. So you could provide the equality comparer wherever you instantiated it.

Answer (score -1):

To get around having to specify the instance of `IEqualityComparer<APerson>` on each instance of the child dictionary what you can do is implment `IEquatable<APerson>` on `APerson` as show in this [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).  In the `Equals` method you can write the actual comparison logic or call the instance of `IEqualityComparer<APerson>` that you already have defined.  The `Dictionary` will detect that the object implements `IEquatable<APerson>` and use that as the default for doing comparisons.

A recommendation for if you go this route would be to have a `Default` field (declared as static readonly) on your `PersonEqualityComparer` such that in the `Equals` method you don't have to create a new instance each time.  So that you have something similar to the following:

```
public class PersonEqaulityComparer : IEqualityComparer<APerson>
{
    public static readonly Default = new PersonEqualityComparer();
}

public class APerson : IEquatable<APerson>
{
    public bool Equals(APerson other)
    {
        return PersonEqualityComparer.Default.Equals(this, other);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        return ((IEquatable<APerson>)this).Equals(other as APerson);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return PersonEqualityComparer.Default.GetHashCode(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you want `Person` to implement `IEquatable<APerson>`, not `IComparer<APerson>` and not have a custom class that implements this (how is the dictionary suppose to find and know to use the implementation, and what if there are two?). `IComparer<T>` doesn't tell the dictionary how to compute hash codes, which is what it really needs, and it needs the way of computing hash codes to be consistent with the definition of equality. Thus, I think it's `IEquatable<T>` and it needs to be implemented on `T` itself.

Comment: @Jason You are correct.  For some reason I couldn't remember what the interface was, I searched for IEqualityComparable.  Thanks for catching that.  I will update the code.

Comment: If you redefine `Equals` it's also important to redefine `GetHashCode`

Comment: @Servy Although the implementation I had didn't override/redefine the base `Equals` function I did update the code to be consistent so that the base `Equals` calls the new interface method so both act the same and added the override for `GetHashCode`